# Can't chat even though I have more than 20 reputation

Tags: bug, chat

Guys I think there is a little bug in Stack Exchange. I have more than 20 reputation on Math SE but it still says "you need 20 reputation to chat" in chat. How do I fix that?

[image]

Here is the link as you said https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/458552/question-no-1

Comment: Did you by any chance post messages under [this chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/458552/question-no-1?tab=recent) (or any other one) in the past? Did you delete your account and later rejoin a site?

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog I haven't delete my account.

Comment: Can you please share a link to your chat profile? You can access this by going to https://chat.stackexchange.com/, switching to the full site using the menu in the top left, then clicking your username in the top right.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog It says page not found. Is my account deleted? Since I changed my profile name and pic right now.

Comment: Can you please edit that information into the question, in addition to the link that is 404ing?

Comment: Still, though, it would be nice to have a link to your chat profile. It'll be helpful for us to know, and easier for the team to diagnose.

Comment: Ah, it seems you previously had an account on Mathematics, which got deleted after you had chatted, and it left your chat profile in a weird state.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog then how to fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1485/discussion-between-question-no-1-i-am-self-taught-and-sonic-the-stay-home-hedgeho).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in a bit of an odd situation.

Your Stack Exchange network profile is linked to your chat account at https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/458552/question-no-1. (You can check this by getting your network ID from your network profile (in this case, https://stackexchange.com/users/17262767/stupid-kid) and then going to [https://chat.stackexchange.com/accounts/\](https://chat.stackexchange.com/accounts/%5C)<id>, or https://chat.stackexchange.com/accounts/17262767 which will redirect to the chat profile linked above.)

However, your chat account is currently *parented* to https://math.stackexchange.com/users/793187/question-no-1, with a user ID of 793187 - which doesn't exist. Evidently, you had a previous Math.SE account that was deleted (at 13 reputation, since that's what your chat.SE profile shows).

Your current Math.SE account is https://math.stackexchange.com/users/793615/question-no-1-i-am-self-taught, with a user ID of 793615.

You *may* be able to change your chat parent user to a different account, such as Meta.SE, which will get you out of your situation by removing the connection to the deleted account. If that's not possible, you can either get the chat profile deleted by a moderator, which will allow you to create a new chat account; or you can wait for a member of Stack staff to fix the situation.

Comment: So how do I change the parent?

Comment: If you go to https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/458552/question-no-1, you should see  a [change] button next to the link back to the parent account (with the Math.SE logo).

Comment: Thanks now it worked! I can chat!